# Find a system point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, determinant, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

Here is given nonlinear ODEs system: 
where $I$ is a control parameter. When $I=I_c$ saddle-node bifurcation is happening. Need to find point $I_c$. By phase plain method via Matlab I ploted nullclines and tried different values of parameter $I$, but I also need an analytical solution of it. I think, first of all I should calculate Jacobian matrix, this form: 
$B=
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
   \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y} \\
  \end{array} } \right)
  $

 
and from it find characteristical polynomial this form: 
\begin{align}
& p_{B}(\lambda)={\lambda}^2 - \lambda Tr(B)+det(B)
\end{align} 

 I don't know what to do later, I guess it should be something related with fixed points or determinant. First time solving this type of problem, so need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

By drawing a graph, we can have a fairly clear idea of ​​what happens in relation to the equilibrium points. In blue we have the trace for $\frac{17.1\, -3 \left(e^{-100 x}+1\right) y}{e^{-100 x}+2}=0$ and in red and green we can observe some parameterizations for $3x-x^3-y +I+2=0$ for some $I$ values. So roughly speaking, we can observe that for $I < -1.92$ and $I > 3.62$ the red curves crosses the blue in one point. For $-1.92<I<-0.02$ the red curve crosses three times the blue and analogously for $1.72<I < 3.62$ and finally, for $-0.02 < I < 1.72$ the curves crosses once. Points where the red, green curve are tangent to the blue curve are noteworthy as possibly bifurcation points.

[image]

NOTE

One of those bifurcation points can be determined numerically with enough precision by solving the following tangency problem. As $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ should be tangent at the bifurcation point, calling

$$
\vec n_1 = \nabla f\\
\vec n_2 = \nabla g
$$

and solving for $(x,y,\lambda)$ the system

$$
\cases{
\vec n_1 = \lambda \vec n_2\\
g(x,y) = 0
}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

we get

$$
\cases{
x_b = 1\\
y_b = 5.7\\
I_b = 1.7
}
$$

At this point the jacobian is

$$
J_b = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 0 & -1.5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The nonlinear system $(1)$ can be solved with the MATHEMATICA commands

```
Clear[f]
f = {2 + x - x^3 - y + i, (17.1 - 3 y (1 + Exp[-100 x]))/(2 + Exp[-100 x])}
n1 = Grad[f[[1]], {x, y}]
n2 = Grad[f[[2]], {x, y}]
NMinimize[(n1 - lambda n2).(n1 - lambda n2) + (17.1 - 3 y (1 + Exp[-100 x]))^2, {x, y, lambda}]
```

FINAL NOTE

Those results can be obtained within a good approximation assuming $e^{-100x}\approx 0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: The condition $\vec n_1 = \lambda\vec n_2$ is on the background.

Comment: This $\lambda$ is a proportional number. It could be called with any other symbol. It has nothing in common with the characteristic polynomial $\lambda$.